# issue with css - class not displayed

Tags: html, css

I ran into an issue I cannot reproduce on my local apache.

A class of my css is not taken into account by my html.

The `positionTitleRec` class is not accepted (e..g color is not displayed). Yet, when I'm putting the other class `positionFrenchRec`, the color is displayed properly

```css
/* nanum-pen-script-regular - latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nanum Pen Script';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/nanum-pen-script-v15-latin-regular.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Nanum Pen'), local('NanumPen'), url('fonts/nanum-pen-script-v15-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('fonts/nanum-pen-script-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('fonts/nanum-pen-script-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('fonts/nanumpenscript-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('fonts/nanum-pen-script-v15-latin-regular.svg#NanumPenScript') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway Script';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway'), url('fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Script';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat'), local('Montserrat'), url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.positiontitleRec {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.1%;
  right: 50.85%;
  top: 3.64%;
  bottom: 60.33%;
  font-family: Montserrat Script;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #E1C89B;
}

.positionFrenchRec {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.1%;
  right: 61.75%;
  top: 10.7%;
  bottom: 45.8%;
  font-family: Raleway Script;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #E1C89B;
}
```

```html
<p class="positionTitleRec">
  Bienvenue
</p>
<p class="positionFrenchRec">
  <br>
  <br>Yo soy Andy.
  <br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your CSS, `.positiontitleRec` needs a capital T as classes are case-sensitive.

Comment: it seems it's not the case here